# php bin/magento setup:upgrade error help

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

I installed a Magento extension and after running php bin/magento setup:upgrade, I get the following errors. I've tried hours trying to find a solution. I even got my server company to help, but no luck.

I'm running Magento 2.3.4 with PHP version 7.2

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function JsonSchema\Uri\filter_var() in /home/thesuitexchange/thesuitexchange/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Uri/UriResolver.php:82
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/thesuitexchange/thesuitexchange/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/SchemaStorage.php(100): JsonSchema\Uri\UriResolver->resolve('file:///home/th...', 'internal://prov...')
    #1 /home/thesuitexchange/thesuitexchange/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/SchemaStorage.php(72): JsonSchema\SchemaStorage->expandRefs(Object(stdClass), 'internal://prov...')
    #2 /home/thesuitexchange/thesuitexchange/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Validator.php(58): JsonSchema\SchemaStorage->addSchema('internal://prov...', Object(stdClass))
    #3 /home/thesuitexchange/thesuitexchange/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Validator.php(78): JsonSchema\Validator->validate(Object(stdClass), Object(stdClass))
    #4 /home/thesuitexchange/thesuitexchange/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Json/Jso in /home/thesuitexchange/thesuitexchange/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema/src/JsonSchema/Uri/UriResolver.php on line 82
```

Comment: I think "filter" extension not enabled on your PHP.

Comment: you need to uninstall that module.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because `ext-filter` not enabled or installed.

Need to install `ext-filter` module. I guess it should be enabled by default.

Alternatively, you can use other approaches on the code side instead of `filter_var()`.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4154711
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1544403

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial for you to set up library justinrainbow: https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/tree/master/vendor/justinrainbow/json-schema